# Flask Python HTML

Tags: flask

I'm trying to render my home HTML file to my main flask python project, but when I run it, it gives this error "jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected '%'" could somebody help? It will be a pleasure. Currently using PyCharm IDE for this project.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
      {{% for post in posts %}}
      <h1>{{post.title}}</h1>
      <p>By {{post.author}} on {{post.date_posted}}</p>
      <p>By {{post.content}}</p>
      {{%end for%}}
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

When doing conditional statements, it must be enclosed with the following syntax:
`{% if true %}`
When passing variables to the template, you use the double braces:
`<span>MyVar has the value: {{ myvar }}</span>`

Another thing to note is that the `end for` should be `endfor`

Answer (score 0):

Flask syntax is like `{% code %}`... not `{{% code %}}`(`{{}}` just for vars to template) and is `{% endfor %}` instead of: `{{%end for%}}`.